# Rails: Foreign key constraint failed when creating variable using let! in RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm working through [Agile Web Development with Rails 6](https://pragprog.com/titles/rails6/agile-web-development-with-rails-6/), but using RSpec for tests with `rspec_rails`, `factory_bot_rails`, and `faker` gems. I'm in Chapter 9 writing some specs testing relations between products, carts, and line items.

The following test causes an error (`ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`) in line 4:

```
context 'DELETE request is invalid' do
  let(:cart)        { create(:cart) }
  let(:prod)        { create(:product) }
  let!(:line_item)  { create(:line_item, cart: cart, product: prod) } # error is here

  let(:run_request) { delete "/products/#{prod.id}" }

  it 'shouldn\'t delete the product' do
    expect(Product.count).to eq 1
  end
end
```

If I remove the exclamation mark, the error is gone because no `line_item` is ever created, but I need to make sure there's at least one line item containing the product I'm about to delete.

What is wrong here? When I use the `create` method to manually create a product, a cart, and a line item in the Rails console, there is no error. This is the rest of my code:

`Product` model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
end
```

`Product` factory:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product, class:Product do
    title       { Faker::Book.title } 
    description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    image_url   { Faker::File.file_name(dir: 'path/to', ext: 'png') }
    price       { Faker::Number.decimal(r_digits: 2) }
  end
end
```

`Cart` model:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`Cart` factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :cart do
    
  end
end
```

`LineItem` model:

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

`LineItem` factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :line_item, class: LineItem do
    product { nil }
    cart { nil }
  end
end
```

*edit: Stack trace*

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:
       SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-6.1.0/lib/factory_bot/evaluation.rb:18:in `create'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-6.1.0/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-6.1.0/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-6.1.0/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-6.1.0/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:43:in `run'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-6.1.0/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-6.1.0/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-6.1.0/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:28:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
     # ./spec/requests/products_controller_spec.rb:51:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # SQLite3::ConstraintException:
     #   FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
     #   /Users/pida/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
```

Comment: Probably one of the "dependent" items are not created properly (cart of prod), please provide full stack trace so we can see.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the stack trace.

Comment: Ugh, not really helpful :(. Try adding bangs to the other lets `let!(:cart)` and `let!(:prod)`. If the issue is with creating any of them - the last line on stack trace (`# ./spec/requests/products_controller_spec.rb:51` should point to the line where this let! is defined (I'm guessing that line 51 is `let!(:line_item)`)